# Is there an Objective-C equivalent to IFNULL?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Consider the code following line of code:

`NSNumber *someNumber = (someOtherNumber) ? someOtherNumber : [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];`

Basically, it says if `someOtherNumber` is not null, use it, otherwise, use 0.  I feel like there should be a better way to do this.  SQL / SQLite have a handy function called `IFNULL` which would make this much simpler.  If it existed, it would make the code look like:

`NSNumber *someNumber = IFNULL(someOtherNumber, [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0]);`

Does something like this exist in objective-c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a contraction of the conditional expression:

```
NSNumber *someNumber = someOtherNumber ?: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
```

and using modern Obj-C you can reduce this further to:

```
NSNumber *someNumber = someOtherNumber ?: @0;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome.  Definitely saved me a ton of keystrokes.

Answer (score 5):

There's a GNU extension to the ternary operator available in Objective-C.

You can use

```
NSNumber *someNumber = (someOtherNumber) ?: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0];
```

The result will be assigned the value of `someOtherNumber` if it is different than `0` or `[NSNumber numberWithInt: 0]` if `someOtherNumber` is equal to `0` (note that `nil`, `NULL` and `Nil` are all forms of `0`).

For extra joy you can reduce your `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]` expression to `@0`. This feature is available staring from [LLVM 3.3](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

**EDIT**

To be more precise this is supported by modern versions of LLVM and GCC, but it's **not** compliant with the [ANSI C specification](http://eli-project.sourceforge.net/c_html/c.html).
That said, you can just go ahead and use it, since you're most likely compiling it with a modern version of either GCC or LLVM.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is nonstandard in C, but since the Objective-C standard is basically "whatever is in Apple's blessed compiler(s)," that is probably not a huge concern if you're already using Objective-C anyway.

Comment: Heh, if you're compiling your Objective-C with POC, almost nothing in the Objective-C tag on Stack Overflow will apply to you.

Comment: Yeah, the note it's kind of rhetorical ^^

Comment: @GabrielePetronella - As you mention ANSI C... Your description with `YES` and `NO` conveys the idea of what is going on, but this is C... Both the `if statement and the conditional expression are defined precisely as selecting the first alternative if the predicate expression is not equal to `0` and the second if it is. And for pointer types "equal to 0" is defined as "equal to null pointer constant". There is no `YES` involved here, the joys of C ;-)

Comment: Legit. "Professional bias" for working with Obj-C most of the time.
Edited my post to be more formal.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define IFNULL(compare, value) (compare) ?: (value)
```

Should do the trick and can be used just like in mysql.

```
NSNumber *foo = IFNULL(someNumber, @0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define like this:

```
#define IFNULL(someOtherNumber) (someOtherNumber) ? someOtherNumber : [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the syntax a bit:  foo ?: bar, will evaluate to foo if foo is non nil, bar otherwise.