# Objective-C syntax: Is ?: part of a ternary operator?

Tags: objective-c

I am looking through some Objective-C code and see the following line that doesn't' make sense:

```
dict ?: @{@"value":value}
```

What does the ?: mean in this context? I haven't been able to find anything about it anywhere, and it kind of looks like a ternary operator, but without the positive return value. Does this just mean return nothing if dict is non-nil, and the other dictionary if it is nil?

Comment: You haven't searched have you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911006/is-there-an-objective-c-equivalent-to-ifnull

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319075/ternary-conditional-operator-behaviour-when-leaving-one-expression-empty

Comment: I did search ?: Objective-C but it didn't come up with those, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's a GNU extension to the C ternary operator and expands to:

```
dict ? dict : @{ @"value" : value };
```